# How to create WizardPage correctly (Eclipse platform)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In the library code after creating page, the assertion check for control property occurs:

```
public void createPageControls(Composite pageContainer) {
        // the default behavior is to create all the pages controls
        for (int i = 0; i < pages.size(); i++) {
            IWizardPage page = (IWizardPage) pages.get(i);
            page.createControl(pageContainer);
            // page is responsible for ensuring the created control is
            // accessable
            // via getControl.
            Assert.isNotNull(page.getControl());
        }
    }
```

(last line)

So, while implementing `WizardPage#createControl` one should fill `control` with something.

In Vogella's sample he created intermediate `Composite` container and uses it: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseWizards/article.html#wizards_example

But may I just use `createContol`'s `parent` argument?

**UPDATE**

What if redefine `WizardPage` class and use it all times?

```
public abstract class WizardPageEx extends WizardPage {

    public WizardPageEx(String pageName, String title, ImageDescriptor titleImage) {
        super(pageName, title, titleImage);
    }

    public WizardPageEx(String pageName) {
        super(pageName);
    }

    @Override
    final public void createControl(Composite parent) {
        Composite control = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        createControlEx(control);
        setControl(control);
    }

    abstract public void createControlEx(Composite control);

}
```

what are disadvantages of such a decision?

Comment: What happens if you try it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `WizardPage.createControl` you must create some sort of `Control` - usually a `Composite` and you must call `WizardPage.setControl(control)` to tell `WizardPage` which is the top level control. So usually something like:

```
@Override
public void createControl(final Composite parent)
{
  final Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NULL);

  ...

  setControl(composite);
}
```